# How to inject share extension' controller into my app?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension

I have a controller with a share `UITabBarButtonItem`:
[image]

Now when I tap on the share button, I need to display sth like this:

[image]

but with different apps: I need Apps for **PDF** or **TEXT**. How to do this?

So far I created app group, add share extension to the project... and, what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use share extension and add a SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem to your share extension for category name.

On click of category name show a list view with all possible options to choose category name and once user select one send image data and selected category name to server.

you can refer this links for more details

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/ios-8-share-extension-photos-ibm-bluemix?lang=en

https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/07/21/ios8-day-by-day-day-2-sharing-extension

Answer (score 0):

Actually I made mistake, I need `UIActivityController` instead of **share extension**.